# A kink is not an immersed submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

My question is:

> Let $S = \{ (x, 0) \in \mathbb R^2: x \leq 0 \} \cup \{ (0, y) \in \mathbb R^2 : y \leq 0 \} \subset \mathbb R^2$. What is the most simple/standard/intuitive way to show that there exists no topology and smooth structure on $S$ for which the inclusion map $\iota : S \to \mathbb R^2$ is a smooth immersion?

(Of course, $\mathbb R^2$ is endowed with the standard topology and smooth structure.)

**Context**

I'm reviewing smooth manifold theory by working through Lee's book, having not touched any math for a long time. The question above distils what I believe to be the essential characteristics of a few exercises in the book (e.g. exercise 5.9, where you are asked to show that a square is not an immersed submanifold in $\mathbb R^2$, and [exercise 5.10](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207593/embedded-submanifold), where you have to show that a curve with a cusp is not an immersed submanifold in $\mathbb R^2$). Therefore, I'd be grateful if somebody could teach me a simple and standard method of tackling this problem, *preferably a method that generalises to a large class of examples including the ones mentioned*.

**My own approach**

Here is my own approach - which, as you can see, is very cumbersome.

Suppose, for contradiction, that $S$ has a topology and smooth structure for which there *does* exist an immersion $\iota : S \to \mathbb R^2$. Let $p = (0,0) \in S$. For every tangent vector $v \in T_p S$, there exists some smooth curve $\gamma : (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to S$ such that $\gamma(0) = p$ and $\gamma ' (0) = v$. Then $\iota_\star(v)$, the image of $v$ under the differential $\iota_\star : T_p S\to T_{\iota(p)}(\mathbb R^2)$, is equal to $(\iota \circ \gamma)' (0)$, the tangent to the curve $\iota \circ \gamma : (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to \mathbb R^2$ at $t = 0$.

Since the image of the curve $\iota \circ \gamma$ lies in subset $\{ (x, 0) : x \leq 0 \} \subset \mathbb R^2$, the $x$-coordinate of $\iota \circ \gamma (t)$ attains its maximum at $t = 0$. Hence the $x$-component of $(\iota \circ \gamma)' (0)$ vanishes. By a similar argument, the $y$-component of $(\iota \circ \gamma)' (0)$ vanishes too. So $\iota_\star(v) = (\iota \circ \gamma)' (0) $ is the zero vector in $T_{\iota(p)}(\mathbb R^2)$.

$\iota : S \to \mathbb R^2$ is an immersion, so $\iota_\star : T_p S \to T_{\iota(p)}(\mathbb R^2)$ is injective. But we've just shown that $\iota_\star$ maps every $v \in T_p S$ to the zero vector in $T_{\iota(p)}(\mathbb R^2)$. So $T_p S$ must be the trivial, zero-dimensional vector space. But then $S$ would have to be a manifold of dimension zero, which would imply that $S$ has the discrete topology, contradicting the requirement that $S$ needs to be second countable in order to qualify as a manifold.

That argument feels very long-winded! I'd be very grateful if someone could suggest a simpler or more standard way to tackle this problem, preferably a method that generalises to similar problems along these lines.

Comment: That's neither a long winded nor a cumbersume argument. It's easy, clear, and obviously correct.

Comment: Okay, good to know that I'm not missing some key idea. Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having slept on this problem, I have realised that my pessimism about the generalisability of my approach was unjustified. The way I went about the problem *does* generalise to a wide range of examples.

I thought I may as well jot down my thoughts in an answer in case somebody looks at this post in the future and has the same doubts.

For example, suppose
$$ S = \{ (-t^3, t) : t \in [0, \infty) \} \cup \{ (t^3, t) : t \in [0, \infty) \} \subset \mathbb R^2$$

This is a *curve* with a kink at $ p = (0,0)$. We want to show that there exists no topology and smooth structure on $S$ such that the inclusion $\iota : S  \to \mathbb R^2$ is a smooth immersion.

To proceed, notice that the intersection of $S$ with the unit ball $B_1(\iota(p))$ lies entirely within the wedge $\{ \mathbf x \in \mathbb R^2 : \mathbf n_1 . \mathbf x \geq 0  \} \cap  \{ \mathbf x \in \mathbb R^2 : \mathbf n_2 . \mathbf x \geq 0 \}$, where $\mathbf n_1 = (\tfrac {1} {\sqrt 2}, \tfrac {1} {\sqrt 2})$ and $\mathbf n_2 = (-\tfrac {1} {\sqrt 2}, \tfrac {1} {\sqrt 2})$.

Therefore, if $\gamma : (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to S$ is any smooth curve with $\gamma(0) = p$, then $\mathbf n_1 . \left( \iota\circ\gamma(t) \right)$ and $\mathbf n_2 . \left( \iota\circ\gamma(t) \right)$ have *local* minima at $t = 0$. This is enough to infer that $\mathbf n_1 . \left( (\iota\circ\gamma) ' (0) \right) = \mathbf n_2 . \left( (\iota\circ\gamma) ' (0) \right) =  0$, which implies that $(\iota\circ\gamma) ' (0) = 0$.

Since $\iota_\star : T_p S \to T_{\iota(p)}(\mathbb R^2)$ is injective, it follows that $T_p S$ is zero dimensional, leading to a contradiction as in my original post.

This approach works for just about any "curve with a kink" that I can come up with. It also works for just about any "surface with a corner" inside $\mathbb R^3$. So this approach *does* generalise quite well, contrary to the pessimism in my original post.

Comment: The argument generalizes to any plane curve passing through the origin and contained in the intersection of two different closed half spaces, for example. it can be arbitrarily complicated subject to that condition.

Comment: Yes, that's what I realised in the end. Thanks very much for taking a look.

Comment: Problem: is a curve which is not contained in the intersection of any two half planes determined by lines with intersection on the curve smooth?

Comment: One example that comes to mind is $S = \{ (-t, 0) : t \in (-\infty, 0] \} \cup \{ (t, \sin(1/t)) : t \in (0, \infty) \} $. If $\gamma : (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to S$ is a smooth curve with $\gamma (0) = (0,0)$, then the image of $\iota \circ \gamma$ must lie entirely within  $\{ (-t, 0) : t \in (-\infty, 0] \} $ due to a path connectivity argument, and then once again, we can conclude that $(\iota \circ \gamma)'(0) = 0$.

Comment: I wonder if we can tackle $S = \{ (-t, 0) : t \in (-\infty, 0] \} \cup \{ (t, t\sin(1/t)) : t \in (0, \infty) \} $ too. I'll put this on my to-do list.